# combination of rectangles, puzzle

Tags: tree, geometry, combinatorics, surface

I have a set of overlapping rectangles, which are all subsets of the biggest rectangle(A), and i want to find combinations of those, so that their union is equal to A. This image illustrates them:
[image]

Restriction: all rectangles should only be used once!

My idea so far is to create a tree with edges determining subsets of the parent rectangle, and to try to puzzle each tree level so that the union of its nodes is equal to the root. This ensures that each rectangle is only used once as well. Since the biggest rectangle(A) is the superset of the others, it is the root.

[image]

So the goal is that the union of as many levels as possible is equal to A, i.e. `D union F union H = A`

But how can i puzzle the other rectangles together to find as many combinations which unions are equal to A as possible?

Comment: "i want to find combinations of those, so that their union is equal to A." Yet in your example, no union of the illustrated rectangles equals A. Did you miss-state your goal, or does your figure not illustrate the goal?

Answer (score 0):

For the puzzling check [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148354/covering-area-algorithm). Since this is a very hard problem, maybe sum the areas first and see whether the sum is equal to the area of A; this will exclude most subsets without any puzzling.

For computing all sets of rectangles look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349220/is-there-an-algorithm-to-find-all-subsets-of-a-set).